# String from slice

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

my function takes String, I understand that this is not very cool, but &String can not use, I want without losing ownership of the original string to pass it into the same function but take a substring from it, in other words:

```
pub fn function1 (s: String) -> i32 {
...
let substring = (&s[index..]).to_string();

counter = function1(substring);
...
}
```

But I get this error:

```
`String` cannot be indexed by `RangeFrom<&_>`
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. Specifically, what is `index`? It should be a `usize`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, index is &i32

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, the implicit type conversion does not work here?

Comment: @student213 the type conversion worked out. Else you wouldn't have the error "'String' [...]"

Comment: Implicit type conversion works as always in Rust. That is, doesn't convert between integer types, not to mention references.

Comment: What do you mean with 'without losing ownership'? I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding of what ownership means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code example is not very complete. The part that actually causes the error can't be seen in your example.

I *guess* that your code looks something like this:

```rust
pub fn function1(s: String) -> i32 {
    let index: &i32 = &1;
    let substring = (&s[index..]).to_string();
    let counter = function1(substring);
    10
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the type `String` cannot be indexed by `RangeFrom<&i32>`
 --> src/main.rs:3:23
  |
3 |     let substring = (&s[index..]).to_string();
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ `String` cannot be indexed by `RangeFrom<&i32>`
  |
  = help: the trait `Index<RangeFrom<&i32>>` is not implemented for `String`
```

### Problems

- `index` must be a `usize`, but it is an `&i32`. This is the main error that you see.
- You cannot slice a string directly, you need to convert from char-based indices to byte-based indices first. This can be done by iterating through `char_indices()`.

Here is a rough sketch of how this might look like:

```rust
pub fn function1(s: String) -> i32 {
    println!("s: {}", s);

    let index: &i32 = &1;

    // Try to convert the index to a byte position
    let substring = match s.char_indices().nth(*index as usize) {
        // If a position with the given index was found in the string, create a substring
        Some((pos, _)) => (&s[pos..]).to_string(),
        // Else, create an empty string
        None => "".to_string(),
    };

    // Break if the substring is empty, otherwise we would have an infinite recursion
    if substring.is_empty() {
        return 0;
    }

    let counter = function1(substring);
    counter + 1
}

fn main() {
    let input_str = "".to_string();
    let result = function1(input_str);
    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

```
s: 
s: 
s: 
s: 
Result: 3
```

### Slicing vs copying

With every iteration of your function, you are creating a new copy of the string.
This is quite slow, and I don't see a reason why this would be necessary in your case.

What you really want is a *slice* of the input string. This doesn't copy any data, it simply references a part of the original string.

To achieve that, you would have to change your parameter type from `String` to `&str`. There is no reason your function would need to take ownership. Even if you want to take ownership, then `to_string()` would do so, as it creates a copy of the data. So there really is no reason to use `String` as the parameter type.

```rust
pub fn function1(s: &str) -> i32 {
    println!("s: {}", s);

    let index: &i32 = &1;

    // Try to convert the index to a byte position
    let substring = match s.char_indices().nth(*index as usize) {
        // If a position with the given index was found in the string, create a substring slice
        Some((pos, _)) => &s[pos..],
        // Else, use an empty string
        None => "",
    };

    // Break if the substring is empty, otherwise we would have an infinite recursion
    if substring.is_empty() {
        return 0;
    }

    let counter = function1(substring);
    counter + 1
}

fn main() {
    let input_str = "".to_string();
    let result = function1(&input_str);
    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

```
s: 
s: 
s: 
s: 
Result: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't indexing a string in rust, because strings are encoded in UTF-8.
You could use the method `chars` and/or `char_indices`

As from your given code, I can't figure out what method you should use. Have a look at the rust doc.

For further information:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.char_indices

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split_whitespace

Comment: But I'm not trying to index by row, I'm trying to take a slice

Comment: more precisely the String from the slice

Comment: Rust didn't allow it. Strings are encoded in UTF-8. And in UTF-8-Strings are not allways ASCII-Only-Strings. You have to iterate through your string.  For example with: char_indices.next()

Comment: I hope this information helps you to find a solution.